# Create <th> element with specific position in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, appendchild

Assume I have 4 “th” elements on the page and on click of the button **I need to create another “th” element but with specific position.**  For example if it’s 1997 it’ll be created in between 1995 and 2000 elements, and so on.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>1990</th>
    <th>1995</th>
    <th>2000</th>
    <th>2005</th>
</tr>
......
```

This is the code I have, but it creates new “th” at the very end.

```
 var tblHeadObj = document.getElementById('<%=Me.GridView1.ClientID %>'); //table head
 var newTH = tblHeadObj.rows[0].appendChild(document.createElement("th"))
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: read the first paragraph

Comment: I did. It doesn't contain a question. Is it how to insert an element at a specific position?

Comment: Or do you want to know how to *get* the position where you have to insert the element? I really can't tell.

Comment: Yes, insert a node in front or after another one. Similar logic as for insertCell(CellIndex), but it can't be used to create <th> element

Comment: As already mentioned in one of the answers, you can do that with `.insertBefore`. Here is better documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aruQOMuT/6/edit)***

```
var doc = document,
    ROW = doc.querySelectorAll("#myTable tr")[0],
    BUTTON = doc.querySelector("#submit"),
    INPUT = doc.querySelector("#setYear");    

function isNumber(n) { // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function createYear(){      
  var VAL = parseInt(INPUT.value, 10);         // GET INPUT VALUE
  var TH = ROW.querySelectorAll("th");
  if(isNumber(VAL)){                           // MAKE SURE IT?S A NUMBER
    for(var i=0; i<TH.length; i++){            // LOOP TH ELEMENTS
      var y = parseInt( TH[i].innerHTML, 10 ); // GET YEAR
      if(y>VAL){                               // ONLY IF y>VAL
        var newTH = doc.createElement("th");   // CREATE NEW TH
        newTH.innerHTML = VAL;                 // INSERT VALUE INTO TH
        ROW.insertBefore( newTH, TH[i]);       // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore
        break;
      }  
    }
  }else{
    alert("PLEASE ENTER A YEAR"); 
  }      
}

BUTTON.addEventListener('click', createYear); // BUTTON CLICK
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out. you could use *insertBefore()*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore

Answer (score 0):

To insert html after the nth element using jquery:

```
$("th:eq(1)").after("<th>1997</th>");
```

...where 1 is your nth element.

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*. If you provide an answer using jQuery, then please add a non-jQuery option as well.